# Numbers in the column of the mysql table are not inserting in correct order

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using MySQL Workbench 6.3. I have a table with two columns id and ingredient. But the id values are not getting inserted properly. Check the images for reference. I have tried both below queries

```
create table ingredients(id int(6) primary key not null, ingredient varchar(30) not null unique);
```

and

```
create table ingredients(id int(6) primary key not null auto_increment, ingredient varchar(30) not null unique);
```

But the output is the same.id column values doesnt come in order. Screenshot of id column:

[image]

Comment: Add an order by id clause to the query.

Comment: Do try and use `VARCHAR(255)` unless you have an extremely compelling reason to limit things otherwise. `VARCHAR(30)` doesn't save any space, it just creates potential truncation mistakes. Likewise use `INT` as its default, not oddball variations like `INT(6)` for no reason.

Answer (score 0):

The order the rows are presented in is arbitrary, though typically it *might* be in order of insertion. If you want them in some particular order:

```
SELECT * FROM ingredients ORDER BY id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * From ingredients
Order By id;
```

The Order By clause will sort the query results.  They will be returned in ascending order by default, if you want them in descending order, put desc after the column name:

```
Order By id Desc;
```